# Android Studioでwrap_contentを使ってもウィジェットのサイズが変更できない

Tags: android-studio

ウィジェットを選択した時点でウィジェットのデフォルトのサイズは存在しないのでしょうか?
wrap_contentはosによって自動調整される機能と解釈していますが.

ウィジェットのサイズを変更をするにはどういう設定をしていますか?
android:widthやheightが反映されません.
LinearLayoutではサイズ変更できないのでしょうか?
絶対的にウィジェットの大きさをDesignmodeで変更する方法は存在しないのでしょうか?
正確に言うと,サイズを調整するためのアイコンみたいなのはDesignmodeで表示されますが,全然動きません.

Answer (score 0):

やや、ご質問から日がたっており解決済みかもしれませんが、チュートリアルを試した後、公式ドキュメントを一読いただくことをお勧めします。

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp?hl=ja
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout?hl=ja

基本的にAndroidの画面レイアウトはレイアウトとウイジェットの入れ子で表現されます。Androidアプリは複数のデバイス、画面向きで実行されるため、それに適応してウィジェットの位置やサイズが自動調整されるレイアウトが推奨されます。(最近の更新ではConstraintLayoutが推奨されるようになりました)

- ウィジェットからwidth,hegithを省略した場合のデフォルトのサイズは両方とも0になります
  'wrap_content'は要素に含まれる内容によりサイズを自動調整することを表します。たとえば画像が含まれていればそのサイズに自動調整されます。
- LinearLayoutは`線形`の配置をします。含まれるウイジェットを指定された向きに従い並べます。この性質からandroid-studioのエディタでは操作しづらくなっています。性質上、通常、幅、高さには`wrap_content`を指定します。
- 絶対値で指定するには`AbsoluteLayout`でウイジェットを内包します。ですがこの要素は非推奨です。

結局XMLでの操作の方がやりやすくなるのでレイアウトはテキストで配置できるようにしておくことをお勧めします